# Phaser 3 increase drag click area size of sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

We have a sprite which we set as interactive

```
this.testSprite = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'button')
    .setInteractive();
```

Now we make this object draggable by adding

```
this.input.dragDistanceThreshold = 20;
this.input.setDraggable(this.testSprite);

this.input.on('drag', function (pointer, obj, dragX, dragY) {
   obj.x = dragX;
   obj.y = dragY;
});
```

Now if we want to increase the size of the draggable area (be able to click a little further to still drag the object), I tried giving the `.setInteractive()` function the additional parameter for the new bounds `new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000)` such as:

```
this.testSprite = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'button')
    .setInteractive(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
```

It doesn't seem to affect this draggable property. Is this the proper way to do it or is there a separate drag size property that I can't find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setInteractive` method of the sprite, to define a valid **hitArea**, that is bigger than the *"button"*, as requested. ([here a link to the docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject.html#setInteractive__anchor)).

Just define a **hitArea** and a **hitAreaCallback**, and it should work.
*(I using the Phaser builtin function to test it the point is in the hitArea, [here the docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.html#.Contains__anchor))*

**Here a working demo:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";    

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}; 

function create () {
    // Padding for the drag Area, just for the demo
    let padding = 50;
    let button = this.add.sprite(50, 50, 'button').setOrigin(0);
    
    button.setInteractive({
        draggable: true,
        // SETUP hitarea
        hitArea: new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(
            - padding,
            - padding,
            button.width + padding * 2,
            button.height + padding * 2 ),
        //Check hitarea
        hitAreaCallback: function(hitArea, x, y){
            return Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains(hitArea, x, y);
        }
    });

    // The following line, is not needed since this option is set in "setInteractive"
    // this.input.setDraggable(button);
    this.input.on('drag', function (pointer, obj, dragX, dragY) {
       obj.x = dragX;
       obj.y = dragY;
    });
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js">
</script>
```

***Info:** This Demo doesn't load an real image, but the placeholder is draggable(with the padding), as nedede.*

> The **hitArea** is relative to the top left corner of the image, thats why the first two parameters, are negative.